# Managing or combining inter linked services in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services

My question is of more of solving the problem in best possible way. I had three services viz., `UrlService`, `PreferencesService` and `LabelsService` which are dependent in hierarchical manner. The `UrlService` consists of all config files urls and REST related urls. One among them `preferencesUrl` is used to load app preferences from the db using `PreferencesService`. From the preferences, the language is taken and the corresonding labels JSON file is loaded using `LabelsService`.

So every time I need some label, I need to go through `UrlService` -> `PreferencesService` -> `LabelsService` and have to write methods like these in every component which uses the labels.

```js
getUrls(): void {
  this.urlService.getUrls()
    .then(urls => {
      this.urls = urls;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

getPreferences(): void {
  this.preferencesService.getPreferences(this.urls['preferences'])
    .then(preferences => {
      this.preferences = < Preferences > preferences;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error.json() || error));
  console.log(this.labels);
}

getLabels(): void {
  this.labelService.getLabels(this.preferences.language)
    .then(response => {
      this.labels = response;
    })
    .catch(response => console.log(response));
  console.log(this.labels);
}
```

I feel like something is terribly wrong in the way I am moving. I tried to combine them but couldn't find a way. Please guide me to achieve this in simple.

Comment: I dont see you using Observables. why is it so?

Comment: You say that they're dependent on each other, in ahierarchical manner. But they are not. Why doesn't the labels service get the language from the preferences service, which would get its url from the url service?

Comment: @Aravind For these services I mentioned, there won't be any repeated requests like in case of a searching something. The data is fixed and will be loaded only once. So I am not using Observables as I read that Promises are enough when there are no continuos stream of events. Is it wrong??

Comment: @JBNizet Because there are different label files for different languages, like labels_en_IN.json for English. Depending on the language, it gets the corresponding url.

Comment: It depends on what is your expectation. Firstly tell me why do you have three end points and three services?

Comment: @Aravind My requirement is this: I am keeping all my labels in a JSON file. I have to load that corresponding JSON file whose language is the users preferred language. And the labels are used over many components. And I am keeping all the urls in asingle JSON file.

Comment: I don't see how that prevents you from doing what I suggest.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry. I didn't get you. How can I decide which JSON file to get without knowing the preferred language of the app. There will be 1 JSON file for one language like English, Telugu, French, for example. And that language is stored in database. Hope I cleared that.

Comment: How are you doing it now? You get the preferred language from the preferences in your controller. Why couldn't the labels service do the same thing?

Comment: @JBNizet Do you mean to use like this: `this.preferencesService.getPrefLanguage()` and use it to load the JSON file.

Comment: @Aravind. Definitely I will. Thank you.

Comment: @Aravind Done. I messaged you.